# How to Get the Latest Updated Values from List in Java?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

Here I am trying to get the latest modifieddate , Like  suppose my entity class is returning 1 value or more then 1 value in that case I need to get the the latest datavalue according to lastmodifiedDate ,

This is my entity class

```
private String data;
private String dataValue;
private Long lastModifiedDate;
```

Here is my service class ..

```
 public void finddata(String id) {
     
            List<Entity> entity =  productRepository.findbyIdAndValue(id,value);
            
               if ((entity != null) && !entity.isEmpty()){
                for (int i = 0; i < product.size(); i++) {
                  entity.get(i).getLastModifiedDate();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Don't do this in memory, just write a proper query to return the result you expect.

Comment: from list I want to get the latest lastmodifieddate and in accordance to that I need the dataValue

Comment: How do you expect for a list if you provide an id as parameter? which interface `ProductRepositoy` implement?

Comment: What do you mean latest? 1 record expected ?

Comment: Right , only one is expected

Comment: `entity` is not a good name for a list of entities. Your `for` loop doesn't do anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your repository is referring to a database it would be best to do the filtering right on the query side.

Otherwise you could use [Stream.max()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#max-java.util.Comparator-) here however:

```java
Optional<Entity> e = entity.stream()
        .max(Comparator.comparing(Entity::getLastModifiedDate));
```

Note that this will throw an NPE for entities without `lastModifiedDate`.